# Convert "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" to "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Tags: c#, string, datetime

As title suggests, what I want to do is to convert my date-string e.g.

- `"6/6/2014 12:24:30 PM"` `(M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt)` format

to

- `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ"` format.

I am trying in the following way. It's not giving me any exception, but I am getting the value like :

- `"YYYY-06-DDT12:24:30.SSSZ"`

How can I exactly achieve this?

```
string LastSyncDateTime = "6/6/2014 12:24:30 PM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(LastSyncDateTime, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = dt.ToString("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Comment: What do you want as an output by the way? You want as `2014-06-06T12:24:30.000` or `2014-06-06T12:24:30.000Z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data time Formats Can't recognize, the non Case sensitive chars in some systems due to their internal settings.  Please refer the below code, which works fine

```
string result = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

The above code will result as `2014-06-06T12:24:30.SSSZ`

EDIT :

The below snippet will give you milliseconds as well

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");
```

Comment: This is working but what about 'SSSZ' characters? Won't these also convert to default miliseconds? Please throw some light on this.

Comment: you should fff for milliseconds not SSS

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the `"o"` date formatter, like this:

```
dt.ToString("o");
```

This method will give you a timestring in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, something like this:

```
2014-12-25T11:56:54.9571247Z
```

but, since that ISO 8601 uses more than 3 decimal digits to define the *second*, if you only want to stop at *milliseconds* you can use the full formatting string and write down `ss.fffzzz` at the end, like this:

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffzzz");
```

and the result will be:

```
2014-12-25T11:56:54.957Z
```

For more informations you can refer to [THIS LIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) of date formatting options.

Comment: I want to convert existing Date into the format stated above not the current date. Can you little elaborate about how can I achieve the same result with example date that I posted? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> but I am getting the value like "`YYYY-06-DDT12:24:30.SSSZ`"

Let me explain why you get this result. Since there is no [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) as `YYYY`, `DD`, `SSS` or `Z`, these characters are copied to the result string *unchanged*.

I strongly suspect you want to use [`yyyy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yyyySpecifier), [`dd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier), [`fff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#fffSpecifier) and [`z`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zSpecifier) format specifiers instead.

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) like;

```
string s = "6/6/2014 12:24:30 PM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffz"));
}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration on Ideone`](http://ideone.com/bzrCX2)</kbd>.

Result will be `2014-06-06T12:24:30.000+3` on my machine because my time zone is `UTC +3` right now. Time zone information *might* change based on your UTC value as well.

Comment: Pretty explanatory answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

`dt.ToString("o");
 dt.ToString("O");`

you can see this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use date in this format :("**yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z**")

Or in manually by changing the time zone you can easily use the date set time zone to (**GMT:000(Greenwich mean time)**) in your setting tab and make sure data type is date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yyyy` for Year and `dd` for date

```
  string result = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick solution:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ")
```